# How to get new changes from main branch to my personal branch on github?

Tags: git, github, git-bash, github-for-windows

There are three branches named 'dev1', 'dev2' and 'main'.
I am working on 'dev2' branch and my friend is working on 'dev1' branch.
We both are fetching and uploading our code from 'main' branch. ('main' branch is the ultimate branch)

Now, suppose I made some changes locally in my 'dev2' branch. Now, I want to push those changes to 'dev2' branch. But, before that, my friend has pushed some changes from'dev1' to 'main' branch. So what should I do?

Please show me step-wise commands for github

for e.g.

step1: git <---do something-->
step2: git <--do something 2--->

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hello, I will gladly answer your question.**

First, you work in local the steps is more similarity in **windows** that **Linux** and other steps in

### Optional Step:

When you are located in your directory, you need to have the branches created, to make sure you have the branches you can do a

```
git branch
```

and quit with "q" key

**It is also important to check that you have your repository created, and connected to your repository**

```
git remote -v
```

---

If not, add your repository, either with HTTPS, or [SSH](https://docs.github.com/es/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh).

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repositoryexample.git
```

---

## Once this is verified, you have to send the branch to github.

> **Here are the step-wise commands you can use to push your changes to the dev2 branch while ensuring that you have the latest changes from your friend's dev1 branch, which have been merged into the main branch.**

## **First Step**

Ensure that you are on the **dev2** branch by running the command in your local repository:

```
git checkout dev2
```

## Step 2:

Next, **fetch** the latest changes from the main branch by running command:

```
git fetch origin main
```

## Step 3:

**Merge** the changes from main branch into your dev2 branch, running the next command:

```
git merge origin/main
```

## Step 4:

Now that your **dev2 branch** is up to date with the latest changes from main, you can push your changes to the remote dev2 branch by running the following command:

```
git push origin dev2
```

This will push your changes to the dev2 branch on the remote repository.

Note: If there are conflicts between your changes and the changes from dev1 branch, Git will prompt you to resolve them before you can complete the merge. In this case, you will need to resolve the conflicts manually before you can push your changes.

---

## Other option

Also, you can just push your **dev2** branch and on GitHub you can work with the Codespace.

- First, ensure that you are on the dev2 branch

```
git checkout dev2
```

- Push the dev2 branch to the remote repository by running the following command:

```
git push origin dev2
```

### Now you can use the **codespace**

https://github.dev/github/dev

---

### Additional info.

> When you have these steps, you would be interested to know how to update your branches from [GitHub](https://docs.github.com/es/desktop/contributing-and-collaborating-using-github-desktop/keeping-your-local-repository-in-sync-with-github/syncing-your-branch) and [manage your branches](https://docs.github.com/es/desktop/contributing-and-collaborating-using-github-desktop/making-changes-in-a-branch/managing-branches).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your current branch(dev1) is up to date with the main branch to avoid conflicts.

You can stash your changes on your current branch(this will store your changes in a stash while you pull the latest on main):

```
git stash
```

Then check out main and pull the latests changes

```
git checkout main
git pull
```

From there you can check out your branch:

```
git checkout dev1
```

Then merge the latest changes from main into your branch:

```
git merge main
```

After that step you can pop your stash into your newly updated branch:

```
git stash pop
```

And now your branch(dev1) has all the latest changes from main as well as the changes you've made locally

Answer (score 0):

Step1: git push dev2 your local changes to dev2 branch. (This wont affect the main branch, or changes made by your friend to the main branch)

Step2: git fetch origin main (Will bring changes made by your friend to local)

Step3: git merge origin/main (will merge your friends changes on main to your local dev2)